# Is it okay importing a database instead of making a migration in laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, api

I want to create an api rest with laravel, and I have already designed my database. However, laravel doesn't allow me to create composite keys. Therefore, my question is, what could happen if instead of using migrations in laravel, I just create my database with sql and then make the corresponding connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free to do anything. You can even overwrite laravel as you wish. You have full control over laravel app. You can do whatever you like. Migration is there to assist you on many ways to create, update your database. This is no difference to what you would do without using it. It will not effect your application. You can import sql, Build your own schema. do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your time!